# Center Align on screen Flex Div with Two Siblings in React Native

Tags: html, css, react-native

I have a react native screen and I am creating my own appBar. What I want to do is show the title of the screen in the center (center) of the device screen. But I also have two side icons which are optional.

So the problem I am running into is if either of the icons is missing then the title of the screen is not exactly in the center of the device screen.

I am using flex for this.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation v4 you can use

```
navigationOptions: {
  headerTitle: <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Title goes here</Title>
}
```